# ADF activities slow down when parallel

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an ADF pipeline that has five 'Execute Pipeline' activities inside.
When I run these sequentially (run activity 2 after completion of activity 1), each activity takes a certain amount of time to run.
When I remove all 'on completion' conditions (run every activity at the same time), each individual activity takes a lot longer to complete. This almost defeats the purpose of running the stuff in parallel, because the difference overall becomes smaller.

I had hoped that the total time parallel would be time of the longest sequentially run sub-activity,  but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Sequential run durations:
[image: Sequential run durations]

Parallel run durations:
[image: Parallel run durations]

as mentioned above, I want to shorten the overall duration by running activities in parallel. I have a self-hosted IR, but not much experience with how this works. Is this an issue of performance capacity?
I don't expect the issue to be related to locking of database tables, because the sub-activities are also parallel execution of CopyData actions. This has worked fine the whole time.

I can also imagine that the answer is just 'this is normal and completely expected behaviour', but I'd like to know if there is something I'm missing.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your pipeline flow image? are you running these inside any loop?

Comment: Parallel activities\pipelines should run faster. The problem is probably a bottle neck on your source, destination, or self-hosted IR machine. Check the resources (cpu,memory etc.) on those machines while running.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above scenario with a wait activity with 10 seconds time inside the child pipeline.

I have used Execute pipeline activity 3 times in the Parent pipeline.

These are the results when I checked and unchecked the **waitOnCompletion** in the Execute pipeline activity.

[image]

You can see that it's taking very less time for the parallel execution.
The parallel execution will start the next activity without waiting for the child pipeline run.

In Sequential or parallel, this won't affect the child pipeline execution time.
So, the problem might be from your activities source or destinations.
Recheck the activity datasets sizes which causing the overhead for your Self hosted IR and making the execution time longer in the parallel execution. Consider scaling it up the memory after some trial-and-error steps as suggested by @[**Chen Hirsh**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21079004/chen-hirsh) in the comments.